# I can't insert data into local database with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I want to make a register form where I have two TextBox elements one for username and one for password and a button. When I press the button the text from the TextBox should be inserted into database.

This is the code :

```
    SqlConnection conn;
    string conectionStrign;

    public Inregistrare()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Inregistrare_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //geting the conectionstring 
        conectionStrign = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Atestat.Properties.Settings.bazaDeDate"].ConnectionString;   
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //creating a conecton to the database 
        conn = new SqlConnection(conectionStrign);
        conn.Open();

        //query for inserting the data from the EditBox 
        string query = "INSERT INTO Utilizatori (userName,password) VALUES (@nume,@parola)";
        SqlCommand comanda = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        //adding value for parameters in command
        comanda.Parameters.Add("nume", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = numeDeUtilizator.Text;
        comanda.Parameters.Add("parola", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parola.Text;
        //execute the comand 
        comanda.ExecuteReader();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: do you get any errors? Does it insert empty data? What exactly is going wrong ?

Comment: What is the result? Do you get any exception?

Comment: have you tried with `comanda.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: it doesn't insert data in DB and i don't get any error

Comment: Are you missing the @ in the `comanda.Parameters.Add`. Does it work if you do comanda.Parameters.Add("@nume", SqlDbType.VarChar).value = numeDeutilizator.Text; ? and "@parola" ?

Comment: doesn't work :( . Do i need to save the database before closing it ore something like that ?

Comment: I think it might add the record to some other mdf file, please try executing select query and share the result object which its returning.

Comment: @GokulanPH I just started to learn C# can you explain me how to share the result from select query ?

Comment: i would suggest you to use Sql Profiler and see what is actually being sent to the database.

Comment: @ClaudiuDumitrel The `ExecuteNonQuery` method I mentioned in my answer returns an integer which is the number of rows affected in the database by the query. Try to debug your code and see if the value is actually greater than zero.

Comment: @Alex the affected numbers of rows is 1 , it should be 1

Comment: Is your connection string pointing to the database you expect it to?

Comment: @Alex i checked it already and the conection string is ok , is pointing where it should be

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `comanda.ExecuteReader()` you should use `comanda.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: does't work i tried

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: the problem is that i don't get any error